# Eloquent hasManyThrough a belongsTo relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm implementing a simple user role and permissions model in Laravel, but I'm not sure if the Eloquent relationship I need exists. I want to return a relationship of User's permissions, but that is via the Role model. A user only has one Role via `role_id`, but a Role has many Permissions.

**Users** belongsTo => **Role** hasMany => **Permissions**

I want an Eloquent relationship method of `User->permissions()` but `hasManyThrough` is not the right relationship structure.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the relation between Roles and Users?, One user has many Roles One user has one Role?

Answer (score 0):

like this.

User

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->role->permissions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `HasManyThrough` relationship:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Permission::class, Role::class, 'id', null, 'role_id'
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have model with name `User.php` `Role.php` `Permission.php`

then relationship define as per below

In `User.php`

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');
}
```

In `Role.php`

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Permission::class, 'role_id');
}
```

Now use this relationship

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::select('id', 'name', 'email', 'role_id')
        ->with([
            'role.permissions'
        ])
        ->find($id);

    $permissions = $user->role->permissions;

    dd($permissions); //here is your permission list
}
```